# Forcing a Tomcat-handled DataSource to be eagerly initialised

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-commons-dbcp, permgen

After eliminating a couple of PermGen-related problems in a Java web application I have reached the following point:

- the application runs in Tomcat 6.0.32 and uses a Tomcat-managed `DataSource`
- the `DataSource` is defined in `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/context.xml`
- when the application starts up it looks up the `DataSource` and only at that time is the `DataSource` instantiated;
- The `BasicDataSource` implementation from commons-dbcp loads the `GenericObjectPool` class, which in turn starts a `java.util.Timer`
- The Timer starts a `TimerThread` which is a GC Root and is loaded by the web application classloader.

**Stacktrace of Timer creation**

```
java.util.Timer.<init>(Timer.java:123)
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.<clinit>(GenericObjectPool.java:268)
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1172)
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:114)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2163)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2159)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1383)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:954)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:855)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:774)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
```

**Timer shown as being loaded by the webapp classloader**

[image: GC Roots]

My first though was to ask Tomcat to initialise the `DataSource` eagerly, thus pinning it in the common classloader, but I found no way of doing that. I'm of course open to other ways of solving this ( but the JNDI-bound resource needs to stay ).

How can I make sure that the `TimerThread` is linked to the web app classloader?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood:
You want your `DataSource` to be loaded exactly once?
Put it in your server.xml as a `GlobalNamingResource`. Reference it in your webapps from the context.xml. (see here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/globalresources.html for more info)

You want it to be loaded for one webapp: Put it in the webapps context xml.

The tomcats context.xml is meant to contain the Resources that should be loaded for all webapps once. (so having 5 webapps results in 5 instances.)

If that did not help, please post your tomcats and webapps context xml.